# AngularJS - How to only change route if something is true?

Tags: angularjs, routes, ngroute

I'm using [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route) from AngularJS.

I have the following code:

```
(...)
    $routeProvider
        .when('/some-page', {
            templateUrl: 'some-page.html',
            controller: 'SomeController'
        })
(...)
```

And i want to open `/some-page` if a condition (e.g. `$scope.isOpenned`) is true. Otherwise, it should redirect to `/other-route`

Comment: This isn't going to work the way you want using `$routeprovider`, since routes are processed before controllers are available (and thus, before `$scope.isOpened` would be).  You would need to control this at the HTML level, or at the controller level.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
<div>
 <a ng-hide="!yourBool" href="#/some-page">Link if True</a>
 <a ng-hide="yourBool" href="#/other-route">Link if False</a>
</div>

<script src="vendors/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
 angular.module('app', [])

 .controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.yourBool = false;

 }]);
</script>
```

Comment: This isn't related with my question.

Comment: this *is* related to your question, as the code is demonstrating how to use `ng-hide` to generate the link conditionally.  as I mentioned in my other comment, this is an example of what is required if you wish access to `$scope`.

Comment: @Claies my question is related to ngRoute.